# What is the best way to convert dynamic xml to a xml of specific format

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a situation where xml of any format( DITA,QTI etc ) should be converted into a common format. Common format xml structure to which other formats to be converted is defined. 
I dono if this can be even achieved. If so what is the best way of doing it.

Options I thought of are,

1)Use Dom or Sax parsers to parse the xml document and then convert it into common format.
Have feeling that this would be very heavy.

2)Use XSLT: Most XSLT syntax expects tags to be known. Not sure if I would be able to do this using XSLT.

As the tag names as well as formats are not known what could be the best way to approach this problem.

Pardon me if this question sounds silly, as I am not very much acquainted with xml parsers and XSLTs yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably XSLT where you transfrom a *source* format to a *target* format, after all, this is exaxctly what XSLT is all about. But, no, XSLT cannot transform *any* source format--you have to specify each combination of source and target, there's really no shortcut there.